# How to send key and check its value in html/django?

Tags: python, html, django

i want to input a key value from user and send to other url which checks if its right or wrong. right being value as "secretkey" wrong being any other value.

My form in html file is:-

```
<form action="/signup/mentor/checkkey" method="GET">
                        Key: <input type="text" name="mkey"><br>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                    </form>
```

and in urls.py

```
path('signup/mentor/checkkey/<mkey>', views.signup_checkkey, name='signup_checkkey'),
```

and in views.py

```
def signup_checkkey(request,mkey):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        messages.warning(request, 'You are already registered as a valid user')
        return redirect(reverse('home'))
    if(mkey == 'secretkey'):
        return render(request=request, template_name='signup/mentor/user.html')
    else :
        messages.warning(request,'Wrong key to register as mentor')
```

but this isn't working correctly. What am I doing wrong?

I get Page not found error...

Comment: in which case you got Page not found error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL is not '...checkkey/', it is just '.../checkkey'. The parameters from the form are not part of the URL.

```
path('signup/mentor/checkkey/', views.signup_checkkey, name='signup_checkkey'),
...

def signup_checkkey(request):
    mkey = request.GET.get('mkey')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Works just fine :)